# Many to many relation with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent

In short I do have a list of contacts and companies.
One company has multiple contacts, but I also want to keep track of the companies the contacts had worked for.

I have a pivot table to create a many to many relation, with one extra column 'contractstatus' so I can see if the contact is still working for that company or not.

What I want is a table with all my contacts.
In one field I want to print out all the companies the contact is still working for.
And via a popup button I want to view the whole working history.

In the contact model I have:

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organization');
}
```

And in the controller I have:

```
public function index()
{
    //get all contacts
    $contacts = Contact::all();

    //load the view and pass the results
    return View::make('contact.index')
                 ->with('contacts', $contacts);
}
```

How can I print out the companies in my views, where contractstatus is active?

And do I need to handle the popup data as a new view file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the pivot data in your query and probably eager load for performance...

```
public function index()
{
    //get all contacts
    $contacts = Contact::with('organizations')->withPivot('contractstatus')->get();

    //load the view and pass the results
    return View::make('contact.index')
                 ->with('contacts', $contacts);
}
```

Then you just loop through the data in your view.  You will probably want to format this better by putting it in a table or something similar.  Hopefully you get the idea.  I just added the classes to get something to grab onto with jQuery.

```
@foreach($contacts as $contact)
    <span class='contact' style="cursor: pointer;">{{{ $contact->name }}}</span>
    <div class='active-organizations'>
        @foreach($contact->organizations as $organization)
            @if($organization->pivot->contractstatus == 'A')
                {{{ $organization->name }}}
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class='all-organizations' style="display: none;">
        @foreach($contact->organizations as $organization)
            {{{ $organization->name }}}
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

As far as the new file to show all organizations, it's really up to you.  I just inserted all organizations into a hidden div so we can show/hide that when the user clicks the contact.  It's very easy with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contact').on('click', function() {
        if($(this).next('.active-organizations').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next('.active-organizations').hide()
            $(this).next('.all-organizations').show()
        } else {
            $(this).next('.active-organizations').show()
            $(this).next('.all-organizations').hide()
        }
    });
});
```